# Can't build a project with a processTemplate.xaml in it

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-process-template

I use VS 2013 and TFS 2013.

I created a brand new solution and followed the steps written here:
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx

minding the difference from his version of vs\tfs and mine.

After I get the process template xaml from the source control, copy it, past it in the Template folder, add it to the project, change the build action to XamlAppDef, try to build the program and I get this error:

Error   2   Extension 'Microsoft.Activities.Build.Validation.ValidationBuildExtension' threw an exception of type 'System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException' :  'The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:
'VisualBasicValue': Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildNumberFormat".
'BuildNumberFormat' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'.  Template

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modifed. Linking to code is ok as long as it's _in addition_ to your posted code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to properties of the template.xaml and set the build action property to none:
http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template

Comment: That merely skips building the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can leave the BuildAction as XamlAppDef. All you have to do to make it compile is add all the required assembly references, including **LibGit2Sharp** from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

and not the NuGet package. If you add the nuget package you'll get an error about a missing strong name.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error as well. My custom activities dll was still created and after I submitted it to TFS and pointed the build controller at it my builds were able to run. The BuildNumberFormat errors were all in my XAML projects, not in my code project.  In my case, this error only appeared to occur when I tried to build locally. My build definitions ran fine.  It is an irritating error but shouldn't stop you from creating your TFS builds.